# How can I use for_each on a list of maps that have nested maps?

Tags: terraform

For example, I want to have a map that represents a channel that receives alerts. Within that map, I have an "alarms" value that is a list of alarm maps. For each channel map, associated resources are created. For each alarm map, associated resources are created and reference resources created from the parent channel map.

```
alarms_list = {
    "alarm-channel1" = {
        channel_description = "Channel description",
        alarms = {
            ServerDown = {
                description = "server alarm description"
            },
            LogError = {
                description = "log alarm description"
            }
        }
    },
    "alarm-channel2" = {
        channel_description = "Channel description",
        alarms = {
            FooDown = {
                description = "foo alarm description"
            },
            BarError = {
                description = "bar alarm description"
            }
        }
    }
}

resource "channel" "this" {
    for_each = var.alarms_list
    name = each.key
    description = each.value.channel_description

resource "alarm" "this" {
    for_each = ....(a resource created for each alarm nested within alarm-channel1"
    description = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flatten your `alarms_list`:

```
locals {

  alarms_list_flat = merge([
    for channel, alarms in var.alarms_list: {
      for alarm_name,v in alarms.alarms: 
        "${channel}-${alarm_name}" => {
          "channel" = channel
          name = alarm_name
          description = v.description
          channel_description = alarms.channel_description
        }
    }
  ]...)  
}
```

then

```
resource "alarm" "this" {
    for_each = local.alarms_list_flat
    description = each.value.description
```